# TTS Wit.Ai Quest 2 Unity change language

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

I would like to change the language for the TTS in my App for my Quest 2.

I'm using the TTS from Wit.AI https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/voice-sdk-tts-overview

There are only English speakers. In the Configuration File the Language is defined as en.

Is there a way to change the language?

[image][image]

There are multiple languages supported here: https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/voice-sdk-built-in

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I haven't found a solution with Wit but now I'm using a diffrent TTS.

Comment: Hello @Severin.Hersche Could you please share different TTS lib that you using? Thanks!